# Способы отловить ошибку внутри docker-контейнера

Tags: python, api, docker

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы поймать ошибку внутри контейнера до его остановки с помощью средств python?

Как вариант, API, которое следит за этим и получает трассировку ошибки, например ?
Спасибо.

Comment: 1. Вы хотите с помощью python найти ошибку в не-python программе? Или ошибка в скрипте python и вы хотите ее найти? Уточните в вопросе. 2. Программы обычно пишут ошибку, по которой вылетают. Если этой информации мало, запускайте программу в отладочном режиме (verbose, debug, ... - это так называется). Что записала программа - можно увидеть в логе докера, вы знаете как это делать?

Comment: Мне нужно с помощью Python отловить ошибку в контейнере docker. Есть такая возможность ?

Comment: Не понимаю, причем тут питон? Запущенная в докере программа выводит ошибки, включите отладочный режим, смотрите ошибки, у докера есть лог. Ничего нет? Тогда запускайте ее через strace, для этого нужно поправить CMD в докерфайле, либо при запуске docker ... прописать strace. Не понятно что за API вы хотите. Напишите, знакомы ли с тем, что я перечислил

Comment: Окей, давайте так. Есть код на питоне, который работает с докер-контейнером. Допустим, внутри него произошла ошибка, необходимо ее отловить кодом питона, который ВНЕ контейнера. Что посоветуете ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, все эти уточнения лучше перенести в вопрос, чтобы он был более конкретен. Это правила SO. По теме - у докера есть логи, их можно получить [по API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs). По умолчанию это сделать нельзя, нужно [определить порт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43713435/9435985)